# Ruby Zip file not found. when file exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubyzip

I am using ruby zip for the first time to read files and i keep getting the error file not found. i even tried putting the file in my public directory and i am still getting the exact same error but if i enter the file location im my address bar the file downloads meaning the file exists.

```
  <% url = URI(request.url) + @design_request.file.url(:original, false) %>
    <% Zip::File.open(url.to_s) do |zip_file| %>
        <% zip_file.each do |entry| %>
            <%= "Extracting #{entry.name}" %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Any help. thanks

Comment: Don't try to read the file over HTTP (`http://my.server.com/my_file.zip`) - read it from your file system (`/home/my_user/my_app/my_file.zip`)

Comment: cool. i have changed it and it seems to be working fine. how can i remove the first entry. cos the first entry is invalid. its the rar folder its self. i used index to sort it out hoping there is a better way.

Comment: `<% next if entry.directory? %>`